# In mithril-js, how can vnode bind to click event

Tags: javascript, mithril.js

In Mithril.js (using webpack), I need to pass vnode to anonymous function:

how can it be done?

```
var Button = {
  view:function(vnode){
    return m('div',{onclick:(vnode)=> setSort(vnode)})
  }
}

function setSort(vnode){
  .... do somthing with vnode ....
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event handlers get passed the `event` object, not a `vnode`. You already have access to the `vnode` via closures, it's passed to your `view` method as the first argument.

```
const Button = {
    view(vnode) {
        return m("button", {
            onclick() {
                console.log(vnode);
            }
        }, "Button");
    }
};

m.mount(document.body, {
    view() {
        return m("div",
            m(Button)
        );
    }
});
```

Here's a [running example on flems.io](https://flems.io/#0=N4IgZglgNgpgziAXAbVAOwIYFsZJAOgAsAXLKEAGhAGMB7NYmBvEAXwvW10QICsEqdBk2J4hcYgAIAQgFdixepIC8k4AB00kyQDcIMAO4AKHWloATGAEo1m7doBOMYrIdasR9SABG8xWi8KWy17bXpqKAhqAGsjGw0Q0O1xWlh8KFoAcxMzSysAbjsk1iLtdkkvOQV6LwKikrRWQoC0LHwsWlkGI3NaalkcBnxvCwBPIITtPUM44NCnFzdJDy9zCB1A0vsPKv8rLbqQhtYCtg4QTBw8fGo4ARp6RmYeNgBdKki0aIQUTiueLAQYiEBzQSggVzkHgkYgABzgiAA9IiurDopkbrQsIjAcDQVAAAIARnwJIAbDigSDoPh+ODiKNYdwQHTWK9WEA).